# Not able to access out parameter in groovy execute stored procedure

Tags: groovy

```
sql.call '{call abcsd_chk(?, ?, ?, ? ,?)}', ['abc1212', '123123','234234', Sql.VARCHAR, Sql.VARCHAR], { result -> println result }
```

getting error in accessing out parameters ,

> No signature of method
>   its.HomeController$_closure83_closure112.doCall() is applicable for
>   argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
>
> Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object), call(),
>   call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object)

didn't able to get the error,

how to iterate the out parameters after executing of procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you defining two out parameters there?

Shouldn't the Closure take them both as parameters?

```
def stmt = '{call abcsd_chk(?, ?, ?, ? ,?)}' 
def params = ['abc1212', '123123','234234', Sql.VARCHAR, Sql.VARCHAR]
sql.call stmt, params, { result1, result2 ->
  println result1
  println result2
}
```